# Stop old posts from reappearing in Facebook News Feed

Tags: facebook

I've recently been given an update of the Facebook App on Android and I have noticed that in my News Feed old posts are appearing. Some as old as a week or more. Obviously the point of a News Feed is to see new things, not old stuff.

How can I turn this off so that I only see new posts appear in the News Feed?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Facebook wants to be smart and recommend posts for you.

If you just want the most recent posts you can press the button top left of the app (some stripes on top of each other), this will open the menu for you. To the right of the 'News Feed' button, there is a gear wheel button, click on it and choose 'Most Recent'.

PS: could be that this is not completely the same in older android versions, I'm talking about 4+

Comment: Yes, confirmed in Android 4.0.4. Yet again, Facebook has got a bit more nippier aka native, but buggy still :(

Answer (score 1):

That is somewhat prevalent glitch in the updated Facebook.

Have discovered earlier, the "somewhat" temperamental cure is this:

- Try logging out and log back in again to clear the cached data.

And also try get in touch via [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana) and there should be a button/linky to email the developers directly about the issue.

Comment: As a developer myself I don't want to recommend the use of commenting on Google Play when something is wrong. Because that is very annoying because you cannot reply. Just send a mail to the developer of those apps (there is a button/link for that)

Comment: +1 ndsmyter, same here, that's true though - have amended my answer based on your comment :)